# How do I setup VS Code for multiple python projects

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I would like to use VS code for multiple python projects. Each of which uses a different virtualenv and has different linting rules.

How can I setup vscode to support this?

Answer (score 1):

You can point vscode to different python executables based off the virtualenv in `.vscode/settings.json`:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "/Users/me/.virtualenvs/.../python"
}
```

and then in your `.vscode/launch.json` use the variable as pythonpath (inside one of the run configurations, which should be auto-generated)

```
"pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
```